# Purrr In R finding last row within a group that meets a criteria and then pulling a value from that row

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

So I think I'm overthinking this one, I've managed to create a functional code, but its incredibly slow and I think that if I use Purrr correctly I will see massive improvements in the functionality of this.

I have a dataset as below

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

Row_ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
Tag <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B")
From_Location <-c("Farm1",
  "Farm2",
  "Farm3",
  "Farm4",
  "Farm3",
  "Farm2",
  "Farm3")
Date <- c("2020-01-06", "2019-08-17", "2019-02-05", "2019-01-01", "2018-04-02", "2020-09-01", "2019-12-23")

Foo <- tibble(Row_ID, Tag, From_Location, Date) %>% 
        mutate(Date = anydate(Date))


# A tibble: 8 x 4
  Row_ID Tag   From_Location Date      
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>         <chr>     
1      1 A     Farm1         2020-01-06
2      2 A     Farm2         2019-08-17
3      3 A     Farm3         2019-02-05
4      4 A     Farm4         2019-01-01
5      5 A     Farm3         2018-04-02
6      6 B     Farm2         2020-09-01
7      7 B     Farm3         2019-12-23
```

I want to identify for each row the last date the tag was on a specific farm. I.e. the last time within that group that From_Location == "Farm3" and then return the "Date" of that column. In my specific use case there will always be a "Farm3" in a row below, as I realize my method breaks due to max() not having an input when there is no row below.

The way I've come up with is creating a function that I can map over which gives me the maximum date. It works but I think there's a better way where Purrr is being used properly

```
FoI = "Farm3"

Last_Date <- function(ID, Row){
  
  dat <- Foo %>% 
    filter(Row_ID >= Row & Tag == ID & From_Location == FoI) %>% 
    .$Date %>% 
    max () %>% 
    as.character()
  
  return(dat)
  
}

Last_Date("A", "4")


Foo_CP <- Foo %>% 
    mutate(Movement_Off_IP = purrr::pmap(list(Tag, Row_ID), .f =Last_Date),
           Movement_Off_IP = ymd(Movement_Off_IP)) 

# A tibble: 7 x 5
  Row_ID Tag   From_Location Date       Movement_Off_IP
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>         <date>     <date>         
1      1 A     Farm1         2020-01-06 2019-02-05     
2      2 A     Farm2         2019-08-17 2019-02-05     
3      3 A     Farm3         2019-02-05 2019-02-05     
4      4 A     Farm4         2019-01-01 2018-04-02     
5      5 A     Farm3         2018-04-02 2018-04-02     
6      6 B     Farm2         2020-09-01 2019-12-23     
7      7 B     Farm3         2019-12-23 2019-12-23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternate approach which I think would be faster than the `purrr` approach since we are not dealing with data row wise.

```
library(dplyr)
FoI = "Farm3"

Foo %>%
  group_by(Tag) %>%
  mutate(Movement_Off_IP = if_else(From_Location == FoI, Date, as.Date(NA))) %>%
  tidyr::fill(Movement_Off_IP, .direction = 'up')

#  Row_ID Tag   From_Location Date       Movement_Off_IP
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr>         <date>     <date>         
#1      1 A     Farm1         2020-01-06 2019-02-05     
#2      2 A     Farm2         2019-08-17 2019-02-05     
#3      3 A     Farm3         2019-02-05 2019-02-05     
#4      4 A     Farm4         2019-01-01 2018-04-02     
#5      5 A     Farm3         2018-04-02 2018-04-02     
#6      6 B     Farm2         2020-09-01 2019-12-23     
#7      7 B     Farm3         2019-12-23 2019-12-23
```

The logic here is that we copy `Date` if `From_Location = FoI` or else `NA`. We replace the `NA` values to the previous dates using `tidyr::fill`.

Comment: Yup, I felt like I was adding too much complexity. That's a much simpler solution that keeps me working rowwise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using rolling joins in `data.table`.

The rolling join is a more precise tool built specifically for this scenario. This will probably be faster for a large dataset.

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(Foo)

#take a subset (just the farm 3 rows)
Foo_farm3 <- Foo[From_Location=="Farm3",list(Date,Tag)] 

#copy the Date column as a new column to be rolled forward:
Foo_farm3[,Movement_Off_IP:=Date]

#do the rolling join:
#(note in a multi-column join, the roll column is the final one specified)
Foo_farm3[Foo, on=c("Tag","Date"),roll=TRUE]

#>          Date Tag Movement_Off_IP Row_ID From_Location
#> 1: 2020-01-06   A      2019-02-05      1         Farm1
#> 2: 2019-08-17   A      2019-02-05      2         Farm2
#> 3: 2019-02-05   A      2019-02-05      3         Farm3
#> 4: 2019-01-01   A      2018-04-02      4         Farm4
#> 5: 2018-04-02   A      2018-04-02      5         Farm3
#> 6: 2020-09-01   B      2019-12-23      6         Farm2
#> 7: 2019-12-23   B      2019-12-23      7         Farm3
```

Or, more concisely using a pipe:

```r
Foo[From_Location=="Farm3",list(Date,Tag,Movement_Off_IP=Date)] %>%
  .[Foo, on=c("Tag","Date"),roll=TRUE]
```

Comment: As a tidyverse person, I feel there's a lot to offer in data.table that I'm not aware of, thanks for pointing me at this to look at. I presume being a data.table solution it will be more efficient.